# Does JavaScript / NodeJS automatically throw Errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, error-handling

I wonder if (for synchronous JavaScript/NodeJS) it does make sense to surround the whole code with try { .. } catch (e) { .. }, even if I myself do not throw any Error in my JavaScript/NodeJS code.

Does JavaScript/NodeJS automatically throw some Exceptions in error cases just like for example Java does?

Comment: Sure, reference errors, syntax errors, type errors, all sorts of errors. Not including of course APIs that throw errors on incorrect usage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does.

Try as code:

```
eval("bla bla bla");
undefined.nomore;
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error for more info.

Comment: I thought `1/0` should evaluate to `Infinity`?

Comment: you are completely correct. Forgot about Infinity and NaN :)

Comment: Well, `bla bla bla` won't throw any exceptions. It's a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks! And all those Errors are catchable by try/catch? Means there is no chance to catch them if they occurr in asynchronous code? (e.g. programatically errors)